# Is there something I am doing wrong with my Content Aggregator Website? I cannot get the articles to show up

Tags: python, html, django

I followed an online tutorial, but was able to scrape different websites. I cannot get the article headlines to show up. I am not sure if it is a problem with my return function or my HTML file. This is the code for the views.py file

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
        import requests
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

        soup = requests.get("https://www.washingtonpost.com/")

        content = bs4(soup.content, 'html5lib')
        headings = content.findAll("div", {"class": "headline 
        relative 
        gray-darkest pb-xs"})
        wpnews = []
        for span in headings:
          wpnews.append(span.text)

        soup2 = requests.get("https://abcnews.go.com/")
        content2 = bs4(soup2.content, 'html5lib')
        headings2 = content2.findAll("div", {"class": 
        "News__Content__Container"})
        for h2 in headings2:
           abcnews.append(h2.text)

        def index(req):
           return render(req, 'news/index.html', {'Washington Post 
           News': wpnews, 'ABC News': abcnews}
```

And this is the portion of the HTML file that's supposed to show the headlines:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                    <h3 class="text-centre"> Washington Post News </h3>
                    {% for n in wpnews%}
                    <h5> -  {{n}} </h5>
                    <hr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                    <h3 class="text-centre">ABC News</h3>
                    {% for htn in abcnews %}
                    <h5> - {{htn}} </h5>
                    <hr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <br>
            </div>
        </div>
python
html
django
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your views.py, change your `render` statement to this:

```
return render(req, 'news/index.html', {'wpnews': wpnews, 'abcnews': abcnews}
```

No matter how unlogical it seems, the text between the quotation marks in your render statement are how the Django template language sees them in your template.

Comment: thank you your answer helped me fix the problem

Comment: Great! Consider marking it as 'the correct answer' by clicking the checkmark to the left side of my answer.